# Sensors for a Smart Bin

Tags: android, geolocation, mocking, sensors

I am working on an app which converts a public trash bin into a Smart Bin. The smart bin will use sensors for Fill-level, humidity, geo-location/GPS, temperature and tilt.

Is there a way to mock data sent by the sensors ? I would like to know what format such data is available.

How will the sensor send such information? Would this be a single sensor or multiple sensors for each use-case ?

Comment: Sensors have to send data in a client-server style communication with both the server and client listening on the same port. The client (trash-can) will send signals, or messages, through the port to the server listening on the other end and the server handles processing the data sent by updating the app. The app can also query the server to have the client send data on command

Comment: Is there a way to mock the data ? So as to know what format / units the data will be guaranteed to be in ?